# How is my parameter not getting to the controller? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-view-controller, parameter-passing

I can clearly see my params getting passed to the controller in the route but somehow my controller isn't picking it up.

For reference:
app `has_many bills` / `belongs_to app`
user `has_many bills` / `belongs_to user`

I have added references in my database to `:app_id` and `:user_id`.

The URL for my `bills` form (i.e. `BillsController#new`) looks like this `apps/1/bills/new` (`1` being the `:app_id`)

**App show view:**
`<%= link_to "New Bill", new_app_bill_path(app_id: @app.id) %>`

**`bills_controller`**

```
 def new
    @app = App.find(params[:app_id])
    @bill = Bill.new
  end
```

**(above works)**

```
  def create
    @app = App.find(params[:app_id])
    @bill.app = @app
    @user = @app.user
    @bill.user = @user
    @bill = Bill.new(bill_params)
    @bill.save

    respond_to do |format|
      if @bill.save
        format.html { redirect_to @bill, notice: 'Bill was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @bill }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @bill.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**(above does not work, returns `nil` for `app_id`)**

**Logs:**

```
Started GET "/apps/1/bills/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-14 09:47:20 -0400
Started GET "/apps/1/bills/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-14 09:47:20 -0400
Processing by BillsController#new as HTML
Processing by BillsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"app_id"=>"1"}
  Parameters: {"app_id"=>"1"}
  App Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "apps".* FROM "apps" WHERE "apps"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  App Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "apps".* FROM "apps" WHERE "apps"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered bills/_form.html.erb (6.0ms)
  Rendered bills/_form.html.erb (6.0ms)
  Rendered bills/new.html.erb within layouts/application (7.2ms)
  Rendered bills/new.html.erb within layouts/application (7.2ms)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 200 OK in 199ms (Views: 189.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
Completed 200 OK in 199ms (Views: 189.3ms | ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)




Started POST "/bills" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-14 09:47:24 -0400
Started POST "/bills" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-14 09:47:24 -0400
Processing by BillsController#create as HTML
Processing by BillsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Vjqma/mhU/RKFCd71VtLyUsvgamzaHqpFsWb56aSkfCz6/5YXXEn+DmNUiyPVR/MphTHJkiCTjUHyIKSEmUQCg==", "bill"=>{"item"=>"gfdsg", "price"=>"fdsgdfg", "status"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Create Bill"}
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Vjqma/mhU/RKFCd71VtLyUsvgamzaHqpFsWb56aSkfCz6/5YXXEn+DmNUiyPVR/MphTHJkiCTjUHyIKSEmUQCg==", "bill"=>{"item"=>"gfdsg", "price"=>"fdsgdfg", "status"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Create Bill"}
  App Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "apps".* FROM "apps" WHERE "apps"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
  App Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "apps".* FROM "apps" WHERE "apps"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find App with 'id'=):
  app/controllers/bills_controller.rb:28:in `create'



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find App with 'id'=):
  app/controllers/bills_controller.rb:28:in `create'


  Rendered /home/nick/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (5.6ms)
  Rendered /home/nick/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (5.6ms)
  Rendered /home/nick/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.3ms)
  Rendered /home/nick/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (2.3ms)
  Rendered /home/nick/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /home/nick/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.9ms)
```

I know I did something dumb and left something out, but I'm just not sure what or where. Let me know if I'm missing any code I should post.

> **EDIT:**

**Form View:**

```
<%= form_for(@bill) do |f| %>
  <% if @bill.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@bill.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this bill from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @bill.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :item %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :item %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :price %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :price %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :status %><br>
    <%= f.check_box :status %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :app_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Re-organized `#create`:**

```
@app = App.find(params[:app_id])
@bill = Bill.new(bill_params)
@bill.app = @app
@user = @app.user
@bill.user = @user
@bill.save
```

**Log output:**

```
Started GET "/apps/1/bills/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-14 11:41:04 -0400
Started GET "/apps/1/bills/new" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-14 11:41:04 -0400
Processing by BillsController#new as HTML
Processing by BillsController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"app_id"=>"1"}
  Parameters: {"app_id"=>"1"}
  App Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "apps".* FROM "apps" WHERE "apps"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  App Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "apps".* FROM "apps" WHERE "apps"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered bills/_form.html.erb (6.3ms)
  Rendered bills/_form.html.erb (6.3ms)
  Rendered bills/new.html.erb within layouts/application (7.3ms)
  Rendered bills/new.html.erb within layouts/application (7.3ms)
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 200 OK in 200ms (Views: 190.7ms | ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 200ms (Views: 190.7ms | ActiveRecord: 2.1ms)




Started POST "/bills" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-14 11:41:07 -0400
Started POST "/bills" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-07-14 11:41:07 -0400
Processing by BillsController#create as HTML
Processing by BillsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Cv4VZRgbw74uExB8/2Hn+aCF98ejKQW+X/3xOsaXHQzvL01WvMu3sl2KZSulb7P8Tb6xSFjDMSJO8OhPcmCc9g==", "bill"=>{"item"=>"fdasfsa", "price"=>"dsafsad", "status"=>"0", "app_id"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Bill"}
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Cv4VZRgbw74uExB8/2Hn+aCF98ejKQW+X/3xOsaXHQzvL01WvMu3sl2KZSulb7P8Tb6xSFjDMSJO8OhPcmCc9g==", "bill"=>{"item"=>"fdasfsa", "price"=>"dsafsad", "status"=>"0", "app_id"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Bill"}
  App Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "apps".* FROM "apps" WHERE "apps"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
  App Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "apps".* FROM "apps" WHERE "apps"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find App with 'id'=):
  app/controllers/bills_controller.rb:28:in `create'



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find App with 'id'=):
  app/controllers/bills_controller.rb:28:in `create'
```

> **EDIT 2:**

**Logs:**

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"jnC5MC04LO691dQOgzkTNk6Bbkq3o5M97b5BnBq5dTproeEDiehY4s5MoVnZN0czo7ooxUxJp6H8s1jprk70wA==", "bill"=>{"item"=>"kjhgkhgk", "price"=>"jhgkhj", "status"=>"0", "app_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Bill"}
  App Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "apps".* FROM "apps" WHERE "apps"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
  App Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "apps".* FROM "apps" WHERE "apps"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find App with 'id'=):
  app/controllers/bills_controller.rb:28:in `create'
```

Comment: It would be nice to see your form in bills/_form.html.erb

Also, you should note that `@bill = Bill.new(bill_params)` should be the first line in your `create` othrewise `@bill.app` will give you "no method 'app' on nil class" and ditto for `@bill.user`

Comment: The `:app_id` parameter in your `get` request will not be automatically included in your `post` parameters.  You probably need to save it has a hidden element in your form so it shows up in your `params` hash when the form is submitted.

Comment: Thank you guys both for your replies. @SteveTurczyn check the edit, I reorganized the method. Thank you.

Comment: @steveklein Thank you sir. I added it as a hidden field in the form to no avail. Is my hidden field incorrect?

Comment: You'll need to populate it with the value from `params`.  Something like `<%= f.hidden_field :app_id, :value => params[:app_id] %>`.

Comment: @steveklein Thank you very much. Check out the second edit's logs. Seems like the parameters are being passed now, but they aren't being put into the controller like they should be `@app = App.find(params[:app_id])` ... `$1 LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]`... `(Couldn't find App with 'id'=):`

Comment: Are you whitelisting your parameters (doc [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters))?  You can inspect your whitelisted parameters to see if they are structured as you expect.

Comment: @steveklein yessir I had perotted them before posting this question. I should've mentioned that in the question. I was under the impression that when a forbidden parameter is passed though the logs express that quite clearly most of the time. However, I know that's an easy thing to forget to do in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing...

```
<%= form_for(@bill) do |f| %>
```

This creates a `post` to the `new_bill_path` which doesn't include the app_id by default (which is why some people go the 'hidden field' method)

However, if you do...

```
<%= form_for([@app, @bill]) do |f| %>
```

That will give you the `new_app_bill_path` which means you'll have `params[:app_id]` for free.

Comment: Good point! I didn't even see your answer, I apologize for not responding, I must be blind

Comment: I'm doing by nested and double-nested elements forms this way, so I don't know why I didn't think to do this. Thank you for your answer, Steve. It's much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In your form, since you already have

```
<%= f.hidden_field :app_id %>
```

Try this in the controller.

```
def create
  @app = App.find(params['bill']['app_id'])

  # rest of the code
end
```

Comment: negative ghostrider. Getting `"app_id"=>" "` ... `[["id", nil]]` ... `(Couldn't find App with 'id'=)` Thank you for your suggestion though, I appreciate it.

Comment: @Nickdb93 since you had `"bill"=>{"item"=>"kjhgkhgk", "price"=>"jhgkhj", "status"=>"0", "app_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Bill"}` as params, that should have worked. try `@app=App.find(params['bill']['app_id'])`

Comment: that's a big ten-four. Why exactly does it work if I pass it as a string rather than a value? Is it because that's how it is in the POST's JSON? How do I use values rather than strings?

Comment: The term `value` is quite wrong, those are `symbols`, which are after all strings. you could add it to the `strong params(permit)` block and see if it takes the symbol. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: I had already permitted those parameters before submitting my question and it did not make a difference

Comment: You could really try the answer by @steveturczyn below, that way you don't even need to define any hidden fields and your original code will run smoothly.

Comment: thank you sincerely for all your help. I didn't see Steve's answer before replying to yours. I believe his solution is cleaner and of better structure, so I really hope I don't offend you by accepting his answer. I really do appreciate your input, and it did certainly help

Comment: I actually remembered we had to do that in order to make the nested resources work after viewing the answer by @steveturczyn. That is in fact the right solution to the problem you were facing.

Comment: yes, that's what I've done with my other nested and double-nested resources and for some reason it had slipped my mind. thank you